# What is the meaning of 声 in ...车市降价声已经是此起彼伏?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of '声‘ in this sentence?

近2/3的进口车也大幅降价;而2004年、2005年和2006年，车市降价**声**已经是此起彼伏。

Comment: how about＂announcement（s）＂ （of price reductions， markdowns） iciba：此起彼伏： As one falls, another rises.; flux and reflux; rise one after another; ... rising here and subsiding there; up here, down there
降价 cut price ； reduce price ； depreciate

Answer (score 5):

"声(Sound)" is metaphorical in this sentence, "车市降价(Automobile market price drop)" cannot actually produce a sound, so it implies that there are potential of market price drop, **because** we are hearing "此起彼伏(Wave after wave)" of the "sound" that automobile market price is going to drop.

Also to mention, "此起彼伏(Wave after wave)" usually describes something that produce waves/has up and downs, so "声" is required or it doesn't make sense.

Comment: it's interesting that this use of 声 appears to be associated exclusively with subjects involving financial markets and/or money: 涨声 is another example.  I wonder whether it stems from the idea of people screaming that prices are falling/rising at actual physical markets.

Answer (score 1):

其实很复杂，这里的“声”表达了降价的趋势、动作，甚至关于汽车降价的新闻和舆论的复合意思。

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what this sentence as a whole is talking about? 近2/3的进口车也大幅降价-- nearly 2/3 of imported cars are getting price drops
;而2004年、2005年和2006年---this is fairly obvious, just those 3 years.

So 声，usually associated with voices and sound, would reasonably be "the CALL(声） for price drop for car market", or "the rumor/voice of price drop ...".

Answer (score 0):

In this context, 声 is short for 对……的呼声

呼声 (cry; voice)

A possible translation in this sentence could be,

> 车市**对**降价**的呼声**
>
> The car market's call for a price cut